# Given the index position of a string, how to get the full sentence?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, slice

I have the index of several words or terms which I am interested in extract from a text file, for example:

```
position = 156
```

The text blob:

```
    1 section react

  The following serious adverse reactions are discussed in greater detail in other sections of the prescribing information:



 *  Peripheral Neuropathy [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.1      )  ]  
 *  Anaphylaxis and Infusion Reactions [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.2      )  ]  
 *  Hematologic Toxicities [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.3      )  ]  
 *  Serious Infections and Opportunistic Infections [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.4      )  ]  
 *  Tumor Lysis Syndrome [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.5      )  ]  
 *  Increased Toxicity in the Presence of Severe Renal Impairment [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.6      )  ]  
 *  Increased Toxicity in the Presence of Moderate or Severe Hepatic Impairment [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.7      )  ]
```

the word is:

```
Peripheral Neuropathy
```

So my questions are:

A) Given a position, how can I extract the sentence, for example:

in:

```
position = 156
```

out:

```
Peripheral Neuropathy .... <the full sentence>
```

B) Given a position, how can I extract the position word with a slice of 100 words

So far I tried to:

```
content[5:-1]
```

And:

```
def extract(start,text):
    return text[start:200+start]

extract(5,content)
```

However, it is returning me the full text, since I am using `-1`. Is there another way of doing this task?

`*` Note that content is a list with the text I am working with.

Comment: _"...how can I extract the pos token with a slice of 100 tokens"_ Is "token" same as a word?

Comment: Ok let me fix the question @AGNGazer!

Comment: _"Note that content is a list with the text I am working with."_ What do you mean by this? Is content a string containing the entire text or it is a *Python  list*? If the latter, then what are the elements of the list?

Comment: it is a python list! @AGNGazer

Comment: A list of what? Characters, words, sentences, etc.?

Comment: it is a list with a text blob! @AGNGazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part A:

```
words = sum(map(str.split, content), [])
sentence = ' '.join(words[position-1:]).split('.')[0] + '.'
```

### Part B:

```
words = sum(map(str.split, content), [])
hundredtokens = ' '.join(words[position-1:position+100]) + '.'
```

Comment: with the part B I got: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @J.Do Works for me if content is a string (which is what I assumed before reading your note). If content is a Python list of fragments (I do not know what a "blob" is) then you may need to create a string first: `content = ' '.join(content)`

Comment: @J.Do Changed the code to work under the assumption that `content` is a list of strings (=="blobs"???)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use regex.

```
>>> mystr = """The effort, led by Shoukhrat Mitalipov of Oregon Health and Science University, involved changing the DNA of a large number of one-cell embryos with the gene-editing technique CRISPR, according to people familiar with the scientific results. Until now, American scientists have watched with a combination of awe, envy, and some alarm as scientists elsewhere were first to explore the controversial practice. To date, three previous reports of editing human embryos were all published by scientists in China."""
>>> import re
>>> match = re.search(r'^(?:\S+\s+){5}([^.]*\.)', mystr).group(1)
match.group(1)
'Mitalipov of Oregon Health and Science University, involved changing the DNA of a large number of one-cell embryos with the gene-editing technique CRISPR, according to people familiar with the scientific results.'
```

Assuming that what you have is a list of words that are in the string, here is an alternative solution:

```
newstr = ""
words = mystr.split(' ')
word_iter = iter(words[5:])
while not newstr.endswith('.'):
    newstr += next(word_iter) + ' '
```

Haha, ok still another solution for what I understand your text in your post to be. I used it as this:

```
mystr =  """*  Peripheral Neuropathy [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.1      )  ]  
 *  Anaphylaxis and Infusion Reactions [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.2      )  ]  
 *  Hematologic Toxicities [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.3      )  ]  
 *  Serious Infections and Opportunistic Infections [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.4      )  ]  
 *  Tumor Lysis Syndrome [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.5      )  ]  
 *  Increased Toxicity in the Presence of Severe Renal Impairment [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.6      )  ]  
 *  Increased Toxicity in the Presence of Moderate or Severe Hepatic Impairment [see  Warnings and Precautions (      5.7      )  ]
"""
```

So first we get the fifth word in the string with regex.

```
target_word = re.findall('\w+', mystr)[4]
```

Then we get the index of it in the string:

```
word_index = mystr.index(target_word)
```

then we create our iterator:

```
word_iter = iter(mystr[index:])
```

then loop through until the end of the line:

```
newstr = ""
while not newstr.endswith('\n'):
    newstr += next(word_iter)
```

Comment: It's hard to know why it's not working if you don't post it. You may need to add `, re.MULTILINE` to the end of the `re.search()` function. like `re.search(r'^(?:\S+\s+){5}([^.]*\.)', mystr, re.MULTILINE).group(1)`

Comment: @J.Do assuming I've understood what you've posted, I've updated it with yet another solution.